# Elastic Beanstalk's cron is run on every environments? How to specify crons for environments

Tags: node.js, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using Amazon ElasticBeanstalk for a node worker application. The application has two different versions deployed on two different environments, and I have two different cron.yaml in these two versions. The goal is to have one worker job specific to the first environment and then common jobs on the two environments.

Somehow, I realized that one of the two cron.yaml is run on both environments. Is that normal ? In this case, how could I achieve what I want, do I really need to create another application for the job I want only on one environment? Am I doing right by using different versions instead of duplicating apps and changing a single env variable?

Thank you.